# Does Jewish/Christian morality apply to angels in the Dominion TV series?

Tags: dominion

I watched the first few episodes of the TV series *Dominion*, which is about a war between angels with humans caught in the middle (based off the movie *Legion*, which I never saw). However, I was kind of surprised to find that the angels seemed rather loose with Jewish and Christian morality (e.g. following the Ten Commandments).

Most notably, the archangel Michael first appears after having slept with a whole bunch of women (violating "Thou shalt not commit adultery"). There are arguably other situations such as killing other angels and humans (violating "Thou shalt not kill", although one could argue this was a just war and was alright) and encouraging the worship of Alex, who is "the savior", rather than God directly (possibly violating "Thou shalt have no other gods before me"), but these are less clear cut.

I'm sure that arguments could be made as to why these actions of the angels aren't truly breaking Jewish/Christian morality and *I don't want to get into a theology argument*, but I think it is clear that at the very least the angels' actions have a gray morality. This was unexpected to me as angels in most other media are portrayed as being very righteous and moral, avoiding anything close to sinful behavior.

My question is, liberal gray interpretation of morality or not, does Jewish/Christian morality apply to the angels in *Dominion*?

Comment: http://blog.cnbeyer.com/tv-and-movies/angelic-morality-in-dominion-and-history/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Within Judeo-Christian theology, Ten Commandments are specifically the laws given to **Israelites** - descendents of Isaac.

   As such, angels - who aren't even human, never mind
   <strike>Druish</strike> Jewish, aren't bound by Ten Commandments.
2. Even if we apply a little less sloppy terminology, and instead refer to seven [Noahide laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Laws_of_Noah) (that are supposed to apply to all descendents of Noah - meaning every human - and include a vaguely worded prohibition of **sexual immodesty** - not adultery - and prohibition of **murder** - as opposed to killing), we still run into the same problem:

   **Angels aren't human**.

   The most important difference between humans and angels (aside from the whole wings and immortality minor details) is that humans, unlike angels, have **free will**. Judaism and Christianity differ somewhat on the details of this:

   - In Judaism, the angels can't sin since they lack "evil inclination" that human do ([reference](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1055341/jewish/Can-Angels-Sin.htm)). They can still make mistakes, but they don't do things "moral" or "immoral" in the sense you imply.
   - In Christianity, it's murikier. On one hand, Judaism's general rules still apply, BUT, there's also Lucifer, who clearly exhibited free will and yet was an angel. BUT... you will note that his main problem wasn't breaking some rule set to humans, but **going against God's will**. As such, again, we can't really judge the angels by laws/morality written for humans specifically.

   Unless in-universe, there is evidence that God explicitly didn't want Michael to do that stuff (and this is impossible since according to the show's premise the whole thing started when God vanished), he didn't commit a sin.

<sub>I won't go into the whole apocryphal Bible books like Book of Enoch, with angels having sex with mortal women resulting in giants and such - or the major theological controvercy over *Nephilim* in Genesis - ... this is SciFi, not [SyFy channel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0421199/)</sub>

Comment: Err...actually this is the SyFy Channel. That's what Dominion airs on.

Also, could you clarify whether it was stated in the show that angels don't have free will? The fact that Gabriel rebelled seems to indicate they do.

Comment: @Thunderforge - Gabriel didn't "rebel". Since there's no God, there's nothing to rebel against. Gabriel made one judgement of what God would have wanted. Michael another.

Comment: @Thunderforge - as far as free will, that's Judeo-Christian theology. I don't think the show covers that (again due to the situation being outside what theology's framework is : God disappeared)